# Access to a specific value from a class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'd like to get access to a specific value from a dictionary.
hopefully someone can help me out with this issue.
thanks in advance.

I've been programming my own adventure game and I want to create a class  and methods for state dictionaries.

```
class state_dict(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_state_dict(self):
        hero_dict = {
            "name": "Hero",
            "lvl": 1,
            "xp" : 0,
            "lvlnext" : 25,
            "stats" : {
                "str" : 1, 
                "dex" : 1,
                "int" : 1,
                "hp" : 30,
                "atk" : [5, 12]
            }
        }
        return(hero_dict)
a = state_dict()
print(a.create_state_dict())
```

Comment: Why is `state_dict` a class at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the `keys` (not `values`) of the dictionary constant? If so, this would be a good use case for a [`dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). In general, `dict` hold many pairs of items -- key-value pairs -- each of which can be quickly added and taken out. A `dataclass` is a way of representing data whose fields -- analogous to the "key" of a `dict` -- it's the correct way of representing a thing whose fields don't change. Anyway, here's one way of implementation a game character:

```
import dataclasses
from typing import List


@dataclasses.dataclass()
class CharacterStats:
    strength: int
    dexterity: int
    intelligence: int
    hitpoints: int
    attack: List[int]


@dataclasses.dataclass()
class GameCharacter:
    name: str
    level: int
    experience: int
    experience_required_for_next_level: int
    stats: CharacterStats
```

The `GameCharacter` would be instantiated like so:

```
willy_the_wizard_stats = CharacterStats(
    strength=1, dexterity=1, intelligence=1, hitpoints=30, attack=[5, 12]
)

willy_the_wizard = GameCharacter(
    name="Willy",
    level=1,
    experience=0,
    experience_required_for_next_level=25,
    stats=willy_the_wizard_stats
)
```

To get the value of Willy the Wizard's name and strength, do

```
willy_name = willy_the_wizard.name  # Willy
willy_strength = willy_the_wizard.stats.strength  # 1
```

Edit: One thing I forgot to mention is, as a rule, it's best to (1) not abbreviate variable names and (2) avoid using keys, field names, etc., any variable whose name is the same as a Python builtin. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) is a list of builtins. Abbreviations may not be easily understood by others and are easy to misspell thus causing bugs. Regarding point (2), using a builtin's name may lead to bugs, for example, wondering why something simple like `range(int(my_variable))` isn't working.